# Can bootstrap 3 HTML templates be modified to work w/ Drupal 8?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drupal, twitter-bootstrap-3, drupal-theming

Much excitement and a couple clicks too many has left me in possession of two things that do not seem naturally compatible: an extensive (compiled I believe--no LESS or SASS folders/files) Bootstrap 3 site template ([Unify](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/unify-responsive-website-template-WB0412697)) and a Drupal 8 installation with the Bootstrap base theme. About 10+ hours of research/testing has got me stumped on this one:

Is it possible/reasonable/efficient to try to modify a generic Bootstrap 3 HTML site template (like the one I purchased) to work with Drupal 8? 
Or is it either or (Bootstrap 3 on its own vs. Drupal 8 + Bootstrap base theme)?

I am interested in understanding if this is something a knowledgeable person could do in an hour or two vs. 10+ hours. If it helps, discrepancies started to add up like so:

- completely different file structure than drupal's theming
- trying to manually include tons of .css and .js plugins in the libraries.yml
- content is hard-coded into the HTML?? so I believe this means re-creating them entirely using Drupal theming(?)

Answer (score 0):

I have done something like this very recently although it was a small project.

Drupal 8 (core) does not have hardcoded HTML anymore (or very very little). You might have different experience with contrib modules.

I don't consider the theme structure a hurdle. It's just a matter of including the right files in the `libraries.yml` file.

The main battle is that you will have to override `twig` files in order to assign the right (bootstrap) classes to elements.

**`input--submit.html.twig`**

For example, this will add the Bootstrap `btn`, `btn-block` and `btn-lg` classes to all submit buttons.

I also customized the submit button to accept an icon attribute (`data-icon`). For existing forms you would need to work with `hook_form_alter` to add the attribute. For your own forms you can just add it to the `#attributes` array.

```
{% set classes = [
    'btn', 'btn-block', 'btn-lg',
] %}

<button{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
    <span class="glyphicon {{ attributes['data-icon'] }}"></span>
    <span>{{ attributes.value }}</span>
</button>{{ children }}
```

**`input--password.html.twig`**

This is for the password form element. I added the `form-control` class.

`<input{{ attributes.addClass("form-control") }} />{{ children }}`

**`block--clean-main-menu.html.twig`**

As another, final, example I wanted to have the site's menu static at the top, so I had to add the `navbar` classes.

```
{% set heading_id = attributes.id ~ '-menu'|clean_id %}
<nav {{ attributes.addClass('navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top') }}>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      {% block content %}
        {{ content }}
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

As I wrote in the beginning this was a small project. You will have a lot more work for bigger projects or perhaps you want to have different styles for different submit buttons (hint: use `hook_theme_suggestions_field_alter` to add new theme overrides).

We work with a lot of 100% customizable themes in my company and completely overriding every little thing is common so we are already used to it ;)

Also, don't forget to install the devel extension. It will help you a great deal when you want to know which `twig` file is being used for what.

Comment: Thank you very much!! :) This is a bit foreign to me right now but I'm very thankful for your response, so I'll dive in! And/or it sounds like I may be able to at least consult with a firm (gonna have to find one though) about the cost of customizing as it may not be too astronomical. Truly appreciate it!